# Transfer File to Unix Server from Windows Shared Path using PuTTY

Tags: unix, sftp, aix, scp, pscp

I need to copy a file from a windows share directory to AIX box.
I am not able to get into windows share directory when i have connected to AIX box.

Can someone please help as which unix commands to use to use to login into windows share directory so that i can copy the file and paste to AIX box

Answer (score 0):

You can copy by using nfsshare. Open nfsshare in windows and mount it in aix.

Answer (score 0):

smbclient (if installed):

```
$ smbclient //host/share
Enter password
smb: \> help
```